# Issue installing docker on Centos 7.3

Tags: docker

I am not able to install the docker on the CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

1.Have enable the extras in the /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
  from enabled=0 to enabled=1
  Also uncommented the #baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/$releasever/extras/$basearch/

2.After that i tried to run the command "yum -y install docker"

I am getting below errors.

Error: Package: 2:container-selinux-2.107-1.el7_6.noarch (extras)
           Requires: selinux-policy-base >= 3.13.1-216.el7
           Installed: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-102.el7.noarch (@anaconda)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-102.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-192.el7.noarch (CentOS-7-x86_64-os)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-192.el7_5.3.noarch (CentOS-7-x86_64-updates)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.3
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-192.el7_5.4.noarch (CentOS-7-x86_64-updates)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.4
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-192.el7_5.6.noarch (CentOS-7-x86_64-updates)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.6
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-192.el7.noarch (CentOS-7-x86_64-os)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-192.el7_5.3.noarch (CentOS-7-x86_64-updates)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.3
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-192.el7_5.4.noarch (CentOS-7-x86_64-updates)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.4
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-192.el7_5.6.noarch (CentOS-7-x86_64-updates)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.6
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.el7.noarch (CentOS-7-x86_64-os)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.el7_5.3.noarch (CentOS-7-x86_64-updates)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.3
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.el7_5.4.noarch (CentOS-7-x86_64-updates)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.4
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.el7_5.6.noarch (CentOS-7-x86_64-updates)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.6
Error: Package: 2:container-selinux-2.107-1.el7_6.noarch (extras)
           Requires: selinux-policy >= 3.13.1-216.el7
           Installed: selinux-policy-3.13.1-102.el7.noarch (@anaconda)
               selinux-policy = 3.13.1-102.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-3.13.1-192.el7.noarch (CentOS-7-x86_64-os)
               selinux-policy = 3.13.1-192.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-3.13.1-192.el7_5.3.noarch (CentOS-7-x86_64-updates)
               selinux-policy = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.3
           Available: selinux-policy-3.13.1-192.el7_5.4.noarch (CentOS-7-x86_64-updates)
               selinux-policy = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.4
           Available: selinux-policy-3.13.1-192.el7_5.6.noarch (CentOS-7-x86_64-updates)
               selinux-policy = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.6
Error: Package: 2:container-selinux-2.107-1.el7_6.noarch (extras)
           Requires: selinux-policy-targeted >= 3.13.1-216.el7
           Installed: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-102.el7.noarch (@anaconda)
               selinux-policy-targeted = 3.13.1-102.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.el7.noarch (CentOS-7-x86_64-os)
               selinux-policy-targeted = 3.13.1-192.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.el7_5.3.noarch (CentOS-7-x86_64-updates)
               selinux-policy-targeted = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.3
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.el7_5.4.noarch (CentOS-7-x86_64-updates)
               selinux-policy-targeted = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.4
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.el7_5.6.noarch (CentOS-7-x86_64-updates)
               selinux-policy-targeted = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Answer (score 2):

If you are installing docker for centos on an aws machine this link is a day saver: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/f99mq1/its_impossible_to_install_docker_engine_on_aws/

> sudo yum update -y 
> sudo amazon-linux-extras install docker
>  sudo
> service docker start

Just make sure that you deleted the repo file before issuing the mentioned commands: /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo

Comment: I spent hours trying to figure out why it wasn't installing and getting dependencies, this seriously saved me so much time! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

### Install Docker Centos7

#### run

```sh
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo systemctl status docker
sudo systemctl enable docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

restart shell and run

```sh
docker info
```

Answer (score -1):

What is the output of `yum repolist -v`? can you try to Install selinux-policy rpm package:`# yum install selinux-policy`   It's possible to show Status of SELinux (Security-Enhanced Linux) like follows. (enabled by default) run this `getenforce` we shall take it from there

Comment: Ok and what was the status then??? you need to give more input in order to get help, we got more important things to do as a matter of fact the only reason I'm trying to assist it's not because of you it's for others,  in case if someone fail's into the same trap so be considerate if you need help...